# How is "infinity" of type Double in Java

Tags: java, oop

This may be a very simple question but I am very confused here.

`Double.MAX_VALUE` gives `1.7976931348623157E308` which indeed is a floating point literal and hence `double`.

However, `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` gives **infinity**. How is **infinity** of type `Double`? It doesn't look like a decimal number or even a number.

Please explain.

Comment: It's a special case

Comment: When you say "gives", are you meaning the string representation? The way a double is converted to a string is described in detail [in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString-double-).

Comment: Maybe you can find the desired answer here:  [JLS §4.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3).

Comment: `double` includes numbers, and it includes infinity, and it includes NaN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At a binary level in IEEE 754 (which is not *exactly* the same as Java floating point), [infinity is represented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Positive_and_negative_infinity) as:

> Positive and negative infinity are represented thus:
>
> - sign = 0 for positive infinity, 1 for negative infinity.
> - biased exponent = all 1 bits.
> - fraction = all 0 bits.

Comment: Thank you so much. That explains everything :)

Answer (score 0):

`POSITIVE_INFINITY` (and its counterpart, `NEGATIVE_INFINITY`) are special constants that Java uses to notify you of overflow of certain operations where the result can no longer be represented as a Double (or Float) value, e.g.

```
System.out.println( 1E300 * 1E20 ); // Infinity
System.out.println( –1E300 * 1E20 ); // -Infinity
```